# Check for file type in FILE jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$('INPUT[type="file"]').change(function () {
var ext = this.value.match(/\.(.+)$/)[1];
var control = $("#uploaded_file");
switch (ext) {
    case 'doc':
    case 'docx':
    case 'pdf':
    case 'wps':
    case 'rtf':
    case 'txt':
    case 'xps':
        $('#uploadButton').attr('disabled', false);
        break;
    default:
        alert('\'' + ext + '\' is not an allowed file type.\n\nPlease select the correct file type:\n\n\t.DOC, .DOCX, .PDF, .WPS, .RTF, .TXT, .XPS');
        $('#uploadButton').attr('disabled', true);
        control.replaceWith(control = control.val('').clone(true));
    }
});
```

Now the issue I have is if a user selects a file which has a ".TXT" it will throw an exception error because TXT is not same as txt, so I tried using the strtolower function. But when I use it the script itself doesnt work.

Modified script with strtolower which doesn't work:

```
$('INPUT[type="file"]').change(function () {
var ext = this.value.match(/\.(.+)$/)[1];
    var cext = strtolower(ext);
var control = $("#uploaded_file");
switch (cext) {
    case 'doc':
    case 'docx':
    case 'pdf':
    case 'wps':
    case 'rtf':
    case 'txt':
    case 'xps':
        $('#uploadButton').attr('disabled', false);
        break;
    default:
        alert('\'' + cext + '\' is not an allowed file type.\n\nPlease select the correct file type:\n\n\t.DOC, .DOCX, .PDF, .WPS, .RTF, .TXT, .XPS');
        $('#uploadButton').attr('disabled', true);
        control.replaceWith(control = control.val('').clone(true));
    }
});
```

Where is the error which is causing it to not work?

Comment: `strtolower()` is a PHP function, not a JavaScript function. You're looking for `String.toLowerCase()` (e.g. `var ext = "TXT"; switch(ext.toLowerCase()) { ...`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that `strtolower()` is a Javascript function. Try `string.toLowerCase()`

```
var cext = ext.toLowerCase();
```

<kbd>[Live sample](http://jsfiddle.net/9rRu9/)</kbd>

**Documentation**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase

Comment: Yes, but please consider linking to a less...contentious source for your supporting references. W3Schools is, basically, [not liked at all for various reasons](http://w3fools.com/). Try [Mozilla's Developer Network documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS).

Comment: Sorry I was so into this coding... i mixed up PHP with JavaScript... lol... I see the error! Thanks